# passing multiple parameters to dispatcher

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have this code working right now in my project.....

```
  def newChannel(cName):
      queue = j.queue(cName)
      r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriberCreateChanTable, subscriberSortScenes])

  def newNetwork(hName):
     queue = j.queue(hName)
     r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriber1a])

  def loginError(nName):
     pass

  def hName(ok):
     return ok[11][1]

  def cName(ok):
     return ok[12][1]

  def nName(ok):
     return ok[10][1]

  def eventType(ok):
     return ok[9][1]


  action = {
     'newChannel': (newChannel, cName),
     'newNetwork': (newNetwork, hName),
     'loginError': (loginError, nName)
     }
```

**How can I tweak it to now accept multiple parameters?**

```
  def newChannel(cName, hname, time):
      queue = j.queue(cName)
      r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriberCreateChanTable, subscriberSortScenes, hname])
      rd = time

  action = {
     'newChannel': (newChannel, cName, ??, ??),
     'newNetwork': (newNetwork, hName, ??),
     'loginError': (loginError, nName)
     }

   ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)
   handler, getter  = action.get(eventType(ok))
   handler(getter(ok))???
```

EDIT:
What if i did this.....

```
         def cName(ok):
             return ok[9][1]
             return ok[12][1]
             return ok[8][1]

         action = {
         'newChannel': (newChannel, cName)
         }

         ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)
         handler, getter  = action.get(eventType(ok))
         handler(getter(ok))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
def prepare_args(ok, *args):
    return [arg(ok) if callable(arg) else arg for arg in args]

action = {
    'newChannel': (newChannel, (cName, hName, whatever,),
    'newNetwork': (newNetwork, (hName,)),
    'loginError': (loginError, (nName,))
    }

ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)
handler, args  = action.get(eventType(ok))
args = prepare_args(ok, *args)
handler(*args)
```

but it might be better to start using a class to provide the context:

```
class QueryHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, u):
        self.ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)

    def newNetwork(self):
         queue = j.queue(self.hName)
         r = queue.add_subscribers(subscriber1a)

    def newChannel(self):
          queue = j.queue(self.cName)
          r = queue.add_subscribers(
              subscriberCreateChanTable,
              subscriberSortScenes,
              self.hname
              )
          rd = self.time

    def loginError(self):
        pass


    @property
    def time(self):
        return whatever_time_is_supposed_to_be

    @property
    def hName(self):
        return self.ok[11][1]

    @property
    def cName(self):
        return self.ok[12][1]

    @property
    def nName(self):
        return self.ok[10][1]

    @property
    def eventType(self):
        return self.ok[9][1]


    actions = {
        'newChannel': newChannel,
        'newNetwork': newNetwork,
        'loginError': loginError,
        }

    def dispatch(self):
        handler  = self.actions.get(self.eventType)
        handler(self)
```

Comment: he's back! that def prepare_args function is what i was missing! your answer combined with @jonrsharpe's explaination is awesome.

Comment: can you explain just a bit. I would like to hear your reasoning. also, thank you.

Comment: what if in the original example i just still called the one param but returned multiple values in the getter function...would that fly...pls see edit @ bottom of post

Comment: whoa...whoa... you just turned it to 1000 on me!! now how do i call that class, how do i put it to use. I'm honestly in the past few days just starting to put oop structures to use in java and python, b/c my project is getting way complex so its necessary

Comment: The "Q&D" / `prepare_arg` solution will only get you so far if you have to add more args - one of it's limitations is that every callable in the `args` tuple will be called (too bad if you need to actually _pass_ a callable - like say a class or a callback function), _and_ it will be called with `ok` as single argument. The class-based version is much more flexible.

Comment: yes there are more arg about 11 or so... you've offered alot already but putting that class to use is indeed my best bet. would that machine i mean class just run in a single file or would i have to call it in another file to rev its engine?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question... It's just like any other Python object, you can define it wherever you want as long as you can make it accessible where you want to use it. If you only need it in one specific script and your script's code is not already too long just stick it in the script. Else it might be time to refactor your script into modules anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for arbitrary parameters in Python is:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args) # positional
    print(kwargs) # keyword
```

Where the `*` is for tuple (un)packing of positional arguments and the `**` is for dictionary un(packing) of keyword arguments. For example:

```
>>> func(1, 2, x=3, y=4)
(1, 2)
{'x':3, 'y':4} # not necessarily in that order
```

You can combine this with specified positional and keyword arguments:

```
def func2(pos1, *args, kw1="3", **kwargs):
    print(pos1)
    print(args)
    print(kw1)
    print(kwargs)
```

which would give:

```
>>> func2(1, 2, kw2=4)
1
(2,)
3
{'kw2': 4}
```

Comment: This is what I've been seeing popping up in all my searches... but i;m having a hard time putting it to my specific case. Do you have the time to walk me through it...using my specific case?